# How do I convert a 3D scanned mesh into a useable/editable model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I have an Artec scanner and would like to use it to scan 3D models and process them in Blender.
Can anyone recommend the best method to use, or work-flow to follow?

Comment: What is the output from this scanner? What export options you have there? Do you have any sample from it?

Comment: Hi Luke, sorry will have to let you know tomorrow. The scanner is linked to my work computer. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2):

Within your Artec Studio software I would export it as a .wrl to preserve the color data. Then in Blender turn on VRML2 import under addons/Import/Export. The import the .wrl. If you don't need color data export as an .obj

Comment: Thank you Othoap, I will have to get back to you on that tomorrow. I didn't expect an answer so soon, and the scanner is linked to my work computer. Thank you for responding.